Manhua about a super strong female lead reincarnated into the life of a girl who was super weak and bullied
I read this really good manhua a long time ago that had a super strong female lead who is reincarnated into the life of a girl who was super weak and bullied. The girl she transmigrated into had a facial disfiguration caused by poison and the female lead cultivated her qi or whatever it's called to remove the poison and start practicing martial arts.
She starts getting revenge on the evil people in her family but keeps running into a man with black hair that she doesn't get along with. The man with black hair had a secret identity and he was also super overpowered but he occasionally turned into a baby ginseng when he was meditating.
EDIT:
I was actually accidentally combining the plots of two different manhuas which was making it difficult to find. The part about the girl having a facial disfiguration is from the ghostly doctor and the part about the guy turning into a baby ginseng is from queen of poison. I’ve literally been scouring the internet typing in random key words until I found it

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. When exactly did you read this?

Over a year ago

What the heck is "a baby ginseng"? Isn't that a root vegetable of some description?

I suspect this is what "a thousand year old ginseng" was 1000 years ago. You know, ginseng is often found in cultivation manhwas, and they can't be old from the start. Maybe dude had accident and went into "vegetable state"?

EDIT:
I was actually accidentally combining the plots of two different manhuas which was making it difficult to find. The part about the girl having a facial disfiguration is from the ghostly doctor and the part about the guy turning into a baby ginseng is from queen of poison. I’ve literally been scouring the internet typing in random key words until I found it

If you post a proper answer (using the 'Your Answer' field below), you may earn some upvotes that will increase your reputation score, if that's of interest to you. If you don't post an answer, someone else probably will, but it might as well be you, since you found it.
